# Mapbox - Error importing classes inside "com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry" package

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox

I'm trying to follow the [Build a navigation app for Android](https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/) by Mapbox, but I'm having an issue with importing classes inside "com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry" package.

The specific error message is: "Cannot find symbol telemetry"

I've configured everything just like in the tutorial, but cannot figure out the problem with the telemetry package.

On Google, there is no one with the exact same problem, so I need your help.

This is my gradle (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hosttrafford.mapboxdemoapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.0.1@aar') {
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.12.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.12.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

And these are the missing imports:

```
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEnginePriority;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.permissions.PermissionsManager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial shown on their website is using Mapbox sdk version 5.

**First Solution**

You can use the version `5.5.2` instead of `6.0.1`.

**Second Solution**

Keep the version 6.0.1 and change the import paths.

```
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineListener
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEnginePriority
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager
```

`Android > Code > Optimize Imports` may help you to find the appropriate classes.

Comment: Both approaches solved the problem! I'll be sticking with the second, so I can use the latest version of the SDK. Thank you @xiaomi !

Comment: @user6159419 What does not work for you ? This is an old answer for the migration to maps sdk v5 to v6. At this moment, the version is v8.6.2. Please check the [sdk reference](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#) which has a migration guide or the [tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/#getting-started)